# Lucene.net escaped characters not found, but un-escaped characters are found - when should I escape?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have a Lucene.net index where one of the fields receives many entries that contain parenthesis.  Before searching against that field, I run my search term through `QueryParser.Escape(searchTerm)`.  If I search for an entry that contains parenthesis, it is not found.  But while running the Visual Studio debugger, I undid the escapes to my search string and the search successfully found my entries.

When indexing the my data, I'm using the Standard Analyzer.  For this field, I'm storing it but not analyzing it.

#### Indexing of the field:

```
doc.Add(new Field("fieldName", fieldValue, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
```

Is there a better way than trial and error to know whether or not (or even which) special characters should be escaped when constructing a `Term` or `TermQuery` object?

### EDIT

#### Searching on the field:

This works:

```
List<Query> queryParts = new List<Query>;
queryParts.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("fieldName", searchValue)));
```

What I first tried, but did not work:

```
List<Query> queryParts = new List<Query>;
queryParts.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("fieldName", QueryParser.Escape(searchValue))));
```

The `searchValue` comes from user input.  The indexed values and search values are both expected to contain parenthesis and possible other characters that have special significance to Lucene.

`queryParts` collects multiple search conditions and is eventually combined into a single `BooleanQuery`, depending upon the user's choices all elements may be combined with either `BooleanClause.Occur.MUST` or `BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD`; after which, that query may be combined with additional search conditions.

Comment: can you provide some search code (QueryParser creation, search code) and what do you exactly mean when you say: "undid the escapes to my search string"?

Comment: @JfBeaulac I assume he's means that he is commenting out the call to QueryParser.Escape(searchTerm) - but it's good to get some clarification and possibly some sample code.

Comment: See what you index before trying to escape your search string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842024/escaping-special-characters-in-lucene-and-query-using-wildcard/7842400#7842400

Comment: @JfBeaulac When undoing the escapes, I right-clicked the watch item in Visual Studio (while debugging) and chose "Edit".  Then I manually deleted the back-slashes before the parenthesis.  Upon saving the changes to the query's deeply embedded Term object's Text property and continuing execution, the search succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres no need for you to use QueryParser.Escape() if you won't use the input to invoke QueryParser.Parse(string).

What happens when you do is that the Escape method will add escape characters to your input, but since you build your Term manually, the escape chars will stay there and lucene attempts so search for them.

> The indexed values and search values are both expected to contain parenthesis and possible other characters that have special significance to Lucene

These characters have special significance to the QueryParser Parse methods, they dont have special significance elsewhere.

Comment: So I only need to escape my input if using the Parse methods?  Do I need to do any escaping with WildCard queries?

    var wildQuery = new WildcardQuery(new Term(field, searchValue));

Comment: yes, the Escape method will escape characters that the Parse method uses to construct Queries from an input string. Since you create your Queries manually, you dont need this method.